# Ruby On rails, colorbox gem, popupwindow

Tags: ruby-on-rails, colorbox

I am trying to use colorbox for my application in Ruby on Rails and I have some problem.

I have installed the gem, added everything in application.css and.js.

When I click on a button for a picture, the window with a picture pops up BUT I cannot close it, the close button doesnt work.
 When the window pops up, the background of the website turns dark grey and in order to close the window, I have to click on the background, it turns light grey and only then I can close the popup window by clicking on the close button.

What can be the problem?
Thanks in advance

edit:
code

```
<% if @files%>    
<%= form_tag destroy_multiple_files_path, method: :delete do %>
<%= submit_tag "Delete selected" %>
  <% @files.each do |file| %>
    <% if (arraydb.file=="no") %>
        <p><td> <%= check_box_tag "files[]", file.id %></td><%= file.name %></p>       

    <% else %>      

    <div class="my_profile_info">     
    <p><td> <%= check_box_tag "files[]", file.id %></td> <%= file.name %></p>        

    <td class="Info">
    <a href="<%=file.info%>" data-colorbox="true" class= "btn btn-mini btn-info">Info</a>  
    </td>  

     </div>

    <% end %>
  <%end%>

<%end%> 
<%else%>

<%end%>
```

Comment: did you find a solution? I am having the same problem. Using web inspector it looks like it's opening the lightbox 2x. So you're actually closing two different lightboxes.

Comment: no. Unfortunately I did not.

Comment: Can i see some of the code you use for initializing colorbox?

Comment: see on console browser, and post some error here if you get error message.

Comment: @anonymousxxx I get no errors

Comment: maybe you including some javascript twice. check your resulting html.

Comment: no, I did not include it twice

Answer (score 0):

This is all in all for colorbox. I used in many rails applications successfully.

http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/

http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/guide/

Comment: I tried it. But I need a gem for ruby on rails. How I tried to use it and what problem I get is writen above.

Comment: Nope its not necessary to use ruby gem for it. I used it multiple times its working fine. I did not completely understand your wording. Kindly elaborate what you are saying.